# Atiyah K-theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

On page 3 of Atiyah's book on [K-theory](http://www.cimat.mx/~luis/seminarios/Teoria-K/Atiyah_K_theory_Advanced.pdf), he states

> Since a vector bundle is locally trivial, any section of a vector bundle is locally described by a vector valued function on the base space.

My question is: what does he mean by this?

I'm sure it's completely obvious but I've   been trying to work out what he means for hours and it just won't click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $p : E \to B$ be a (real for example) vector bundle. It's locally trivial, meaning that if you take a small open set $U \subset B$, then you can find an isomorphism $\varphi : p^{-1}(U) \cong U \times \mathbb{R}^n$, compatible with $p$ (meaning that $\varphi(\xi) = (p(\xi), \text{something})$).

Now a section $s : B \to E$ of $p$ is a map such that $p \circ s = id_B$. So if you restrict to the small open set $U$, then $s(b) \in p^{-1}(\{b\}) \subset p^{-1}(U)$, therefore $\varphi(s(b)) = (p(s(b)), \text{something}) = (b, \text{something})$. Call the "something" $\sigma(b)$ (it depends on $b$), then you get a map $\sigma : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (determined by $s$). This is what is meant by "locally a section is given by a vector valued function on the base space": the vector valued function is $\sigma$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your help.